# Using data in file for equations. Python 3.4

Tags: windows-10, python-3.4

How would I go by taking data from a file, seperage the x's and y's, and still be able to use those numbers to find slope, y-intercept, and correlation coefficient. I have all the equations down, but I just can't seem to use the data as an integer. I'm not home so I don't have my program on me yet and if it'll make it easier then I can post what I already have when I get home but I've been stuck on this for 4 days and nothing will work.

Comment: The x values come after an 'x=' and the y values came after a 'y='. It's a very simple file with only those two things in it

Answer (score 0):

how are the X and Y values separated in the file?

Comment: The x values come after an 'x=' and the y values came after a 'y='. It's a very simple file with only those two things in it